# Ошибка спецификатора переопределения при подключении заголовочного файла

Tags: c++

При подключении заголовочного файла выбивает ошибку:

> 1>E:\VisualST19Comm\Projects\Tutorials\nums\testHeader.h(22,16): error C3646:  getdel: неизвестный спецификатор переопределения
>   1>E:\VisualST19Comm\Projects\Tutorials\nums\testHeader.h(22,16): error C2059:  синтаксическая ошибка: (
>   1>E:\VisualST19Comm\Projects\Tutorials\nums\testHeader.h(22,19): error C2334:  непредвиденные лексемы перед "{"; пропуск вероятного тела функции

Как только убираю функцию getdel() в классе, все прекрасно работает. Что не так?

Код:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class testClass {

    public:

        bool isDel(int arg) {
            if (arg % deling == 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        void setDeletel(int arg) {
            deling = arg;
        }

        string getdel() {
            string gotDell = to_string(deling);
            return gotDell;
        }

    private:

        int deling;

};
```

Comment: Ну правильно: перед `getdel` стоит необъявленный идентификатор `string`.

Comment: Так я хочу, чтобы функция возвращала string

Comment: Ну тогда этот тип необходимо где-то определить

Comment: Во блин, спасибо за намек) Забыл про std. Сенк ю)

Comment: Ломал голову час)

Comment: Вам стоит начать использовать какую-нибудь IDE, в той же VS для таких простых проблем прекрасно работают встроенные автофиксилки.

Comment: Использую VS community 2019

Comment: А вообще, другая сторона автофиксилок - новичку, то бишь мне, тяжело будет научиться писать правильно) Лучше буду четыре часа сидеть и ломать голову, но зато научусь делать грамотно и правильно